# How to find MagneticField Strength using magnetometer in android

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, magnetometer

I want to get Magnetic Field Strength from magnetometer of Android Device.

Using the magnetometer of android device I can get the data of magnetic field in the form of x,y & z axis in Micro Tesla.

But I don't know how to find magnetic field.

Any suggestion, Idea or Sample code are appreciated. . .

Comment: I tried to use GeoMagneticField method, but then I realize that it can give me a magnetic field but the magnetic field I get is not from the Magneto meter but its Magnetic Field of earth. I can get the values of x,y & Z axis from magneto meter but I can't understand using that, How can I get Magnetic Field?

Comment: hello have u find the voltage using this magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding your question.

Do you want the absolute value of the magnetic field instead of the components?
It this is the case, it is enough to calculate the module (the square root of the sum of the squared values of every component).

The facto of having three components gives you more information: Not only the magnetic field but also the direction of it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am already calculate the magnetic field using three components with ( float magnetic_field = (float) Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y)+ (z * z)); ) function.  But Now I don't know how to find voltage using this magnetic field. Any Idea regarding this. . .